# Responding to kaddish in pesukei dezimro

Tags: halacha, tefilla, kaddish

If I am saying pesukei dezimro, I can only make some responses to kaddish (Tefillo Kehilchoso, 10 (50)).

[OC 51 (4) [8]](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14170&st=&pgnum=156) and Biur Halocho d.h. tzorich refer to this but do not specify the permitted responses.

Please can I have an earlier source than Tefillo Kehilchoso?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the source that you cited in the Mishna Berura and Biur Halacha, there does not seem to be any distinction made between the different responses with kaddish. All seem to be ok during Pesuka deZimra.

> ביאור הלכה: ...ומכל מקום, לענין קדיש...נראה לי פשוט דבפסוקי דזמרה יפסיק לכל זה, אף במקום דלא סליק ענינא

[Edit: New Sources]

However, the sefer *Ishei Yisrael*, gives the guideline to only say *Amen Yehei Shemei Rabba...Almaya*, and then the *Amen* after *d'amiran b'alma*, but **not** to say Amen to any of the remaining lines in the Kaddish (*titkabel*, *yehei shelama rabba* and *oseh shalom*).

The source cited for this is the Mishnah Berurah, 66, s.k. 17. where this is given as a guideline for when to respond and when not to respond *amen* during the recitation of the *shema*. The distinction made there regarding the Amems after *titkabel*: "כי אינו אלא מנהג" - that they are only said because it is customary to do so (but not because they must be said). The source for the Mishna Berurah is the *Magen Avraham* on the same *siman*, s.k. 6 (the מחצית השקל there explains that really kaddish should end right before *titkabel*).

So it looks like these different books on *hilchot tefillah* are using the definition of the MB/MgA for the permissible Amens in Kaddish when interrupting Kriyat Shema, and are applying it to Pesukei d'zimrah as well.

Comment: Thanks, Yaakov, yes. But Tefillo Kehilchoso and the back cover of the Tefillas Kol Peh both exclude all omains other than before yehai shmai rabboh and after da'amiron be'olmo.

Answer (score 3):

[Igrot Moshe OC 2:16](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=918&pgnum=187) says not to answer 'brich  hu' during psukei dezimra.