# What comprises a hefsek in Mincha?

Tags: shemoneh-esrei, kaddish, hefsek-interruption, mincha-afternoon-prayer, mishnah-berurah

When we daven mincha, we say the psalm we call "Ashrei" first. This seems to come from The shulchan aruch, O"C 93:2. This section requires that the amida be "samuch" to the psalm.

We say kaddish after the psalm. Why isn't this a hefsek? I was reading some of the related questions regarding kaddish in maariv. Amidst all the questions and answers was [this](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/61274/1362) which says that the kaddish is not a hefsek because its content echoes the geulah requirement.

[other resources: [Answering "Brich hu" to the kaddish before shemone esrei at maariv](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/11514/answering-brich-hu-to-the-kaddish-before-shemone-esrei-at-maariv) and
https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/36259/1362 which posits that the kaddish allowed because maariv is optional]

If the smichut is not geulah based in mincha, how can we say kaddish there without its being a hefsek?

The Mishnah Brurah writes in 108:2 (13) that one davening a make-up amida should insert ashrei before the second one to ensure the proper smichut, but earlier, the mechaber wrote in 105 that the break between 2 prayers should be very short in order to maintain the right mindset. In the end of (13) it seems that the M"B says that 105 is a bediavad case and 108 is lechatchilah.

What is the general rule about smichut in mincha and how does kaddish fit in?

Comment: It's not a real smichus, that's why we get to stick in extra stuff like ki shem Hashem ekra etc. But +1 and hope you get a good answer.

Comment: @user6591 I would like that but then I wonder why the mechaber equates them in 93:2. I would the also wonder how much of a hefsek is allowed is smichut isn't essential.

Comment: Yeah, it's definitely something that can get a good answer. I think the idea I mentioned from the Magen Avraham is built upon a bit in the igros moshe. I'll see if I can find you that maareh makom.

Comment: I had sent this maareh makom to someone else recently, I'm not sure if he directly addresses your issue but you may find something. See igros moshe orach chaim 5 page 82 first paragraph that starts on that page in the name of Magen Avraham begining of siman 111.

Answer (score 1):

I think the answer is in your words, and that your assumption that "the smichut is not geulah based in mincha" is not accurate.

It is true that the main and important *smichut* is in the morning prayers, but as the *Shulchan Aruch* says [(92, 2)](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%9F_%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9A_%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%97_%D7%97%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%A6%D7%92):

> לא יעמוד להתפלל אלא באימה והכנעה לא מתוך שחוק וקלות ראש ודברים בטלים ולא מתוך כעס אלא מתוך שמחה כגון דברי תנחומין של תורה סמוך לגאולת מצרים או סמוך לתהלה לדוד שכתוב בו רצון יראיו יעשה שומר ה' את כל אוהביו:

The main idea is to start the *amida* prayer out of joy **such as** *geulat Mitsraim* and *ashrei* (they are brought as examples for joy before the morning and mid-day prayers).

In the morning *tefillah*, specifically, there's a "stronger" *halacha* of joining the story of the Exodus to the *amida* prayer, so even *kadish* isn't allowed. But since *kadish* does eventually speak of *geulah* and future days of *mashiach*, it does not constitute a real *hefsek*, therefore for the rest of the prayers (*mincha*, *mussaf*, *maariv*, etc.) it's OK.

**Edit:** Finally found a [source](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=33610&st=&pgnum=29) that speaks about this issue specifically, and brings a few opinions about it (if there's an issue of *smichut* in *mincha* or not).

Comment: the source seems to be saying that there is no smichut of geula and tefillah in mincha, not that there isn't any smichut in mincha. 92:2 gives examples of essential smichut, stating geula and ashrei as equivalent. The idea that kaddish continues the concept of geula is what allows its being said in maariv because that's the prayer which emplys the smichut of geula. Musaf has NO smichut so kaddish is allowed. But mincha HAS a smichut, just not geula.

Comment: There's the idea of *smichut* of **geulah** specifically, and the idea of that the *Shulchan Aruch* states as starting the prayer out of joy. Those are two separate ideas and *halachot*. There are several *poskim* who try to understand when do we have to insert *geulah* before prayers (maybe only in the morning, maybe always, etc.), and that is what the last source I brought speaks of. However, there's the "standard" *smichut* of simple joy, which is always true, but *kadish* cannot be said to be a *hefsek* of joy.

Comment: The text doesn't indicate a geulah of simple joy, but of דברי תנחומין של תורה . Is that your claim about kaddish?

Comment: The Shulchan Aruch quoted is about joy: "מתוך שמחה". Then come the examples, "כגון דברי תנחומין של תורה", etc. But the subject is joy, and the rest are examples. This is not the same as the *halacha* of *smichat geulah litfila*.

Comment: if kaddish were not a hefsek of the joy, then there would never need to be the answer that kaddish is no hefsek because it continues the concept of geula (http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/61274/1362) and if geula is simply one of the examples of joy and kaddish is also joy, then there should be no problem of saying kaddish in shacharit.

Comment: There is a difference between the **joy** concept and the **geulah** concept. The **geulah** concept is in *Shulchan Aruch* 66, 8-10. The questions about *kaddish* are relevant there. However, the *Shulchan Aruch* also writes general comments about *tefilah*, honoring it and starting it in the right "mood". This has to do with the **joy**, and this is a less formal *halacha*, and here he gives the **examples** of *geulah* and *divrei torah*, but *kaddish* does not interfere.

Comment: How does one determine that 92:2 is a "less formal halacha" and that the 2 examples there are not equivalent?

Comment: You're right, that wasn't a correct choice of words. One *halacha* (93) is about praying out of joy, and it just makes sense (to me) that *smichut* here isn't the strict *smichut* of *geulah litfilah*, since the joy will not be affected by the *kaddish*. The other *halacha* (66) about *smichat geulah litfilah* does speak strictly of no pauses, and that's why the *Shulchan Aruch* himself immediately emphasizes this (don't pause even for *kaddish*, *kedushah*, *amen*, etc.).

Comment: There is a conroversy as to whether semichut ge'ulah letefilla is needed for Ma'ariv, BTW.